# DeleteStaleTemplateCaches/tasks error

Tags: control-panel, cache, tasks

I've got the ol’ `DeleteStaleTemplateCaches` issue breaking the Craft task manager/process. I've tried switching the offending task over to `error` from `running` but is still stuck.

Any thoughts on debugging/resolving? Can I just clear out the tasks table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to help debug why tasks sometimes get "stuck": https://craftcms.com/help/stuck-tasks